# Get the number of pages and file names of pdf files using PDFtk and write it to excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdftk

I am new member, i will do my best efforts to be specifc and clear and respect the time of the members.I am a begginer in VBA and need your help.

I am using a free version of the program PDFtk that shows information about pdf files through a graphical interface (you can see the attached picture).

[PDFtk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFej.png)

The program show for each pdf file 2 types of information:

1. The file name
2. The number of pages

However, i'm looking for a VBA macro that will retrive that information (file name, number of pages) and then write it to an open workbook in excel.

It's important that the VBA will search for pdf files at specific location in my computer c:\temp

and then write to excel somthing like this:

[Excel filenames and number of pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkdQu.png)

In another words, a need a VBA that can do the job without "really" opening the graphical interface, and yet use the PDFtk application to get the correct number of pages.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your question appears misdirected. Instead of focusing on a tool that has a graphical interface, you should probably look for a tool having a textual interface that you can analyze in your VBA code. There appears to exist at least one such tool called pdfinfo.

Comment: Pdfinfo indeed count the number of pages correctly. It can be a good solution for me, but i have no idea how to write a VBA code that analyze all the pdf files located in  c:\temp in my computer and then write the information into excel. I really don't care which tool to use as long as it is free. pdfinfo seems to good suggestion .If you have any idea how to write a VBA that uses  pdfinfo, and retrieve the number of pages to cells in excel, I would  appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this (source: [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5330-excel-vba-pdf-page-count.html))

```
Sub Test()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileNum As Long
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.pdf", vbDirectory)
        Set xRg = Range("A1")
        Range("A:B").ClearContents
        Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        xRg = "File Name"
        xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "Pages"
        I = 2
        xStr = ""
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            Cells(I, 1) = xFileName
            Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
            RegExp.Global = True
            RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
            xFileNum = FreeFile
            Open (xFdItem & xFileName) For Binary As #xFileNum
                xStr = Space(LOF(xFileNum))
                Get #xFileNum, , xStr
            Close #xFileNum
            Cells(I, 2) = RegExp.Execute(xStr).Count
            I = I + 1
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
        Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link and thanks for your reply.

I have already tried that link couple of weeks ago.

I also tried this method- https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-page-count.347911/  VBA code written by Haluk at year 2008, and although giving better results it still make mistakes.

After reading a lot about this subject i realized that a VBA that doesn't use a third party program make a lot of mistakes regarding counting pdf pages.

sometimes count more pages than the real, sometimes less than the real, sometime count zero, Counting pages Is very tricky and without a program it is not reliable.

I read an explanation why counting pdf pages without third party program is tricky
https://www.reddit.com/r/visualbasic/comments/29n2xa/getting_pdf_page_count/

Until now I found only one vba that always give the correct number of pdf pages - a vba that use adobe acrobat professional - which means using a third party program which is not free. This is not an option for me.
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-40734.html

I prefer a free solution, and for that reason i need a vba that use a free third party program, for example PDFtk ,pdf sam basic.
Pdf property extension also count pages correctly- it is a lightweight COM extension that brings back PDF properties and columns to Windows Explorer – but I have no idea how to write a vba for it. https://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/pdfpropertyextension